# Wi-Fi NIC is failing after about an hour - Surface Pro 3 | running 5.1 Hera

Tags: wifi, drivers, surface-tablet

I have a driver issue or something that is causing my Wi-Fi to intermittently fail. This is a Microsoft Surface Pro 3 tablet. Here's the Wi-Fi NIC config:

```
crimKid@ElmnlryOS-SP3:/etc/pm/sleep.d$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for crimKid:         
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: 88W8897 [AVASTAR] 802.11ac Wireless
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 00
       serial: 4c:0b:be:0d:65:dc
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mwifiex_pcie ip=192.168.3.32 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:59 memory:c0500000-c05fffff memory:c0400000-c04fffff
```

I checked the output of `dmesg` but there was far too much and I didn't know what to grep for. How can I fix this?

Update: I did find this when running grep against `dmesg`

```
crimKid@ElmnlryOS-SP4:~$ dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.186908] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.226436] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.870961] [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (98)
```

I googled the above, but apparently there is some argument as to whether or not this is a bug...? https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=69921

Comment: This link help you ? https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface

Comment: I'll try it out - thank you, @LinkPhoenix!

Comment: If this solves your problem do not hesitate to answer yourself. I am also curious to know if Github project makes it possible to operate Linux under a Surface.

Comment: Looks like that fixed the issue! THANK YOU!! :) Please do write it as an answer and I will accept!